# Sending secure data from .NET to Linux server using POST?

Tags: mysql, .net, linux, http, post

Is POST method inherently "secure" and if not, can it be easily made secure or should I use a different protocol entirely?

Please back your statements up with explanation or reference unless they are simply opinion.

The system:

- .NET program collecting data with a QR scanner
- a web server running CentOS 6
- a database on the server to store scans in tables based on QR type.
- not all QR types are known now so a new table is created when a new QR type is to be sent.
- data needs to get from QR scanner to database as quickly as possible but assume connection is unreliable (think cell phone tethering)

Feel free to comment on my (incorrect?) assumptions about the validity of these other methods I've discounted.

- opening a port for MySQL and pushing data in directly - makes IT people panic even if the user has very restricted privileges although I don't see how it's insecure. (also see comments on ssh + MySQL)
- using ssh tunnel to insert to MySQL - it's quite conceivable that the database structure will change in the future and I want all the MySQL work done server side so it's easy to modify.
- making my own listener on a port on the server and defining my own protocol - seemed daunting at first glance. I know C++/C/Python/PHP so I could do something like this if POST is bad and listener is easy. Don't know where to start or scope of this method.

Example of data packet to be sent. (This is what my .net DLL must receive from the previous person) [QRTypeVersion, HeaderLength, H1, H2, ... DataLength, D1, D2 ..., Comment]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some good reads:
There are some really good comments about security.

[Is either GET or POST more secure than the other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/198462/is-either-get-or-post-more-secure-than-the-other)

[how to secure POST method without using SSL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5088944/how-to-secure-post-method-without-using-ssl)

[How secure is a HTTP POST?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008668/how-secure-is-a-http-post)

Hope this helps.

Comment: These are good sources. From these, overall I get the feeling SSL plus POST is a decently secure way to go. Still not sure if it's right for this application.