# Login info going as plain text - How to make it unreadable

Tags: php, jquery, html

I'm doing a login form that uses jquery to pass data from the form to the script and back. I've noticed the email and password are being sent as plain readable text. I also noticed that in other site like this very one, or gmail or others, the login info isn't readable like mine is. How can I do this? Somehow, sending this info as plain text doesn't look very... professional.

[image: Screen Capture FireBug]

Comment: If not as plain text, how are they sent? What do they look like? Unless you use https (which you _should_ do for logins!!!) they will be sent in plain text.  Some sites may base64 encode before sending, but that amounts to little more than obfuscation. https will protect it.

Comment: Use [SSL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Sockets_Layer).  Set up `https:` on your server.

Comment: That's exactly what SSL _encryption_ is for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you have several options here:

1. Use HTTPS protocol to send the login informations.
2. You can hash/encrypt your login info on the client side, upload it/process the form, and decrypt and process the login info on your server. SO have several Q/A answers regarding this process:

   - [Two-way password encryption without ssl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38838/two-way-password-encryption-without-ssl)
   - [Secure login: public key encryption in PHP and Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1528012/secure-login-public-key-encryption-in-php-and-javascript)

However, options #2 is not really an options, if the encryption key are also submitted in plain text over the internet.

Comment: Option 2 shouldn't really be considered an option, since it doesn't add any security (which is mentioned in the answers you linked).

Comment: @Emily: true, I should've added that info on my answer *updating*

Comment: Ok. I'll have a look at SSL. Will speak to my web host about it.